# Why can't I use su to run under another app's permissions?

Tags: root-access, permissions, superuser

It's well-known that every Android app is its own user. I have Android Terminal Emulator installed as user **u0_a5**.

```
u0_a5@android:/ $ whoami
u0_a5
u0_a5@android:/ $ groups
u0_a5 sdcard_rw sdcard_r inet all_a5
```

Under adb, any attempt to use the **su** command to log in as Android Terminal Emulator only partly succeeds. As the following adb session shows, the permission groups that Android Terminal Emulator belongs to aren't inherited, except for the default user **u0_a5** group.

```
root@android:/ # su - u0_a5
Unknown id: u0_a5
1|root@android:/ # su - 10005
app_5@android:/ $ whoami
u0_a5
app_5@android:/ $ groups
u0_a5
```

As user **10005** I can delete files owned by user **u0_a5**. But I can't execute commands that require special Android permissions, such as "busybox wget protocol://some.uri", which requires an app to belong to the **inet** group.

So is there a way to impersonate and run an app under its specific permissions environment? Or is running with full root permissions my only (non)choice?

Answer (score 2):

Yup using **root** is the only way to go.

All other groups or username are locked in userland of Android by a technique known as **sandboxing**. This is security feature implemented at the core so you will need to rework  Android if you still want to succeed.

Comment: That "sandboxing" keeps one app from accessing another apps data etc., true. But once one becomes root, this does no longer matter (root can enter any sandbox). So the really interesting question is: why can't root enter a sandbox, and then "give up" all extra permissions but those belonging to this sandbox? This would be what the OP targets at.